# Visual Studio extension custom command error: "Object does not match target type"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I want to create a Visual Studio extension. More precisely an additional menu item. I used this tutorial as a guideline:

[Visual Studio Extensibility: Creating Visual Studio VSIX package extension](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37071.visual-studio-extensibility-creating-visual-studio-vsix-package-extension.aspx)

The problem is after I created successfully a VSIX project, I tried to add a custom command. While the custom command is added to my project the following error occurs:

[image: ![enter image description here]

After pressing "ok" a .cs file is added to my project. This file has few  reference errors. I also tried to reference the source file by myself, but without success.

[image]

It also gives the following output:

> Adding a new custom command 'Command1' to the project 'MockGenExtension':
>     The custom command requires a VS package. No existing VS packages found in the project. A new VS package 'Command1Package' will be created for the custom command.

I already reinstalled the Visual Studio and the SDK without any effect.

Comment: Is Visual Studio 2015 fully updated? I tried it locally on version 14 update 3 (Community edition) and it works.

Comment: @hegu_141, What about this issue now? I could add the custom command well in my VS2015 with update 3(Enterprise version). Is it related to the update like nejcs' suggestion. Or your VS Extensibility Tools was not the update 3 version.

Comment: It hasn't worked with my fully updated Visual Studio 2015. After few reinstallations I  decided to upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 and voila it works fine now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @hegu_141, The latest VS would be a better choose, since you would use the VS2017 and it works well now, you could add it as an answer, and then mark it. Have a nice day:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 fixed the problem for me.